# laravel 5 polymorphic pivot

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, polymorphism

I want to ask whether is a option to make polymorphic connections between 2 tables based on id and type with pivot table like this:

Where table TABLE_* can be for example TABLE_BOOKS or TABLE_MAGAZINE or whatever.

description:

```
=> - "has"
... - "other attributes"
FK - "foreign key"
```

database:

```
TABLE_* => ID, FK_TYPE_ID,...
SHELFS_WINDOW => ID, FK_TABLE_*_ID, FK_TYPE_ID,...
TYPE => ID,...
```

Where is SHELFS_WINDOW  for one book so there is polymorphic One to One relationshop. I'm able to reach the TABLE_* only with ID and type of the table from document for example. But the type of TABLE_* is in another table with some other informations.

Now I want to know whether is there any posibility to create this relationship with a clean way. Yes, I know, I can do it with \DB:: class. I want to stay in database with SELECTion and I don't want to lose functionality from the returned object Builder.

So I'm just asking whether is there any possibility to do it or not. Or maybe another approach.

Thank You for help!

**EDITED:**
Create select with \DB class and select desired table (even with multiple joins) without returning object and create this object array then set on the model guarded =[ ] and set $fillable to all then create a new Object model and fill it with created array. Then u have to set exists = true and return nice Eloquent object.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the function on your eloquent model,
eloquent will use this function to determine the table that should be used

```
    public function getTable() :string
    {
        //perform your id / type specific table logic here
        return $tablename;
    }
```